# Python/Discord -- When i try to make a folder it is in my desktop instead of the designated folder

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is the current code:

```
   if message.content == "MMO start":
        dir=(r"C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\MMMOProfiles")
        file = str(message.author)
        path = os.path.join(dir,file)
        isExist = os.path.exists(path)
        if isExist == True:
            await message.channel.send("You already have a profile")
        elif isExist == False:
            await message.channel.send("Creating profile")
            file2 = str(message.author)
            dir =(r"C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\MMOProfiles")
            os.mkdir(file2)
```

When I try to make it create the folder though it is in the desktop instead of the folder on the desktop.

Comment: You are never changing the current working directory, and you aren't building a directory name using `file2` *and* `dir`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will check if the folder in the desktop, if not it will create the new folder:

```
newpath = r'C:\Users\mooqa\Desktop\ss' 
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
os.makedirs(newpath)
```

Comment: Can I carry over some of the old code to make it use message.author?